# Docker High Availability for Stateful Applications Between Geographically Distant Datacenters

Tags: open-source, postgresql, mongodb

What is the FOSS solution that provides High Availability to stateful docker apps between geographically dispersed data centers?

- OS: CentOS 7
- FOSS: no support contract
- Specific requirements: HA/failover of stateful Docker containers (mongodb/postgres) between data centers.

Comment: The problem is that I need to figure out which questions to ask. I think that I need ceph in conjunction with REX-Ray to achieve my goal, but the configuration/architecture is really the conundrum that I am trying to figure out. It seems to be out of the scope of this site.

Comment: Well, it's asking for software now, so it seems legit.

Answer (score 0):

For Databases it depends on the Database/Use case:

Postgres: Postgres BDR with HAProxy

MongoDB: Replica Sets and modify API URI to mongodb://db1.example.net:27017,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test

Though Mongodb can be used with HAProxy, the Mongodb's internal failover system has to be disabled and it would probably be easier to just change the URI as stated above.

The native replication/failover functionality needs to be used for the database and sometimes proxied to.

For other persistent Docker volumes, DRBD would probably be sufficient.